# type-casting can be an example of adapter design pattern?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, casting, adapter

Adapter design pattern resolved the incompatibility between two incompatible interface or objects.

If native type casting is performed:

```
float a = 2.5;
int b = (int)a;
```

Does the adapter design pattern apply here?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Answer (score 2):

No. Since an adapter pattern requires Object instances, and type-casting primitives uses no Object(s) at all, it isn't an Adapter pattern. Even if you cast between Object instances (which you could only do if they were in the same type-hierarchy), it would not be an adapter pattern. From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) (emphasis added), the adapter pattern is a software design pattern that allows the interface of an existing class to be used from **another** interface.

Comment: Every class in Java descends from Object. They form a tree. You can cast an instance to a less specific ancestor. For example, you can cast everything to an `Object`. That **does not** make it an `Adapter`.